# Gather speech and digits concurrently?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

Is there a way to do a gather that accepts either digits or speech?

If someone types digits at any point in the call, I'd like to transfer them to the correct department. At the same time, I'm also collecting speech from them using Gather for speech.

Wondering if its possible to do both.

Working with Node

Answer (score 0):

You can choose `dtmf speech` for the [input](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#input). This means the first detected input (`speech` or `dtmf`) will take precedence. If `speech` is detected first, `finishOnKey` will be ignored.

There's no way to make the them run without any taking precedence. That would probably get too confusing for callers.